# Projects handler program

Tags: project-management

In our company we need a project handler so we decided to write our own.
We use CMake and bazaar and we still don't know if to store the informations of the 
projects in XML format or in a database.
We are locked at this point: we would like to use as less languages/tools as possible
but we cannot find a way to interface CMake with XML files or databases.
An idea could be Python but it would be really annoying to use a new language just for an interface. We've seen that there's a Python framework (Waf) but we have already used CMake for all our projects and it would take a lot of time to convert all.
We work with Ubuntu and Windows.

Suggestions ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Rather than make your own tool, use an off-the-shelf product like something from the Jira suite, or BuildMaster. Many of these have great integration with most build software and don't require you to write and maintain your own stack just to manage projects.

Focus your developer time on solving your business problems, not on reinventing the wheel. Their time is MUCH more valuable than the cost of using a ready-made solution.